# Update Message (CrmService) Dynamics 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to update the fields like "`cs_hv_additionnalparticularities`", "`cs_hv_smscope`" and so on, but the function `srv.Update(de);`updates all the form records, I mean it triggers a workflow that I don't want it to happen.
here is my code:

```
 // Retrieve the DynamicEntity that goes with target
        RetrieveRequest retrieve = new RetrieveRequest();
        retrieve.Target = target;
        retrieve.ColumnSet = new AllColumns();
        retrieve.ReturnDynamicEntities = true;
        // Create a response reference and execute the retrieve request.
        RetrieveResponse response1 = (RetrieveResponse)srv.Execute(retrieve);
        DynamicEntity de = (DynamicEntity)response1.BusinessEntity;


            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_additionnalparticularities"))
                de["cs_hv_additionnalparticularities"] = opp["cs_hv_additionnalparticularities"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_smscope"))
                de["cs_hv_smscope"] = opp["cs_hv_smscope"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_ugscope"))
                de["cs_hv_ugscope"] = opp["cs_hv_ugscope"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_acdc"))
                de["cs_hv_acdc"] = opp["cs_hv_acdc"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_smmv"))
                de["cs_hv_smmv"] = opp["cs_hv_smmv"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_smhv"))
                de["cs_hv_smhv"] = opp["cs_hv_smhv"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hv_ughv"))
                de["cs_hv_ughv"] = opp["cs_hv_ughv"];
            if (opp.Properties.Contains("cs_hvid"))
                de["cs_hvid"] = opp["cs_hvid"];
            de["cs_generercable"] = new CrmBoolean(true);

           srv.Update(de);
```

I don't want to use this function `srv.Update(de);` to update the fields. 
Can somebody please give me the update function code that can do this work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to update additional columns, just retrieve the specific columns (property `ColumnSet`) instead of the `new AllColumns()`.

You can use only the update the record with the `Update` method, make sure that your workflow triggers only for the requested fields, and not for additional fields.